# JQuery Timesheets or a Jquery Calendar with timeline like this

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I looking for a plugin in jquery to make a calendar or a timesheet like this picture:

[image]

I just found [this plugin](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml), but isn't what I looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown resembles more of a Timeline View that a calendar.
(It looks closer to GANTT Chart, especially with the time summaries on the right)

I'm not to current on "Open Source" alternatives but have a look at the following components:

GANTT Demos:

https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/

SCHEDULER Demos:

https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/

If your developing using php there's also a composer package which is quite useful:

composer require dhtmlx/connector-php

I've been experimenting with their GANTT package using Laravel and there's some detailed tutorial examples to be found if you google using dhtmlxgantt with laravel (sorry I couldn't post more than two links as I'm a new member)